# Can i access variable inside another variable? PHP

Tags: php, variables, get

In PHP, is visible to access variable that is inside another variable?
in my case i need to access $value (from $output1) and $value (from $output2) independently. how to do that? thanks

```
if ($nilaineg > $nilainet && $nilaineg > $nilaipos) {
  $output1 = '<div class="message"> ' . $tweet . ' </div>
     <div class="hasil">'.**$value** .'</div> </div>';
}
else if ($nilaipos > $nilaineg && $nilaipos > $nilainet){
   $output2 = '<div class="message"> ' . $tweet . ' </div>
      <div class="hasil">'. $value .'</div> </div>';        
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? In current situation this is not clear.

Comment: What you actually needed here?

Answer (score 2):

`$value` isn't "inside" `$output1`. `$value` is a variable just like `$output1` which is used in a string concatenation. You can still use `$value` outside and independently of the string concatenation and `$output1`.

```
$output1 .= '<div class="message"> ' . $tweet . ' </div>
             <div class="hasil">' . $value . '</div> 
             </div>';

echo $output1;
echo $value;
```

Comment: Hi @deceze thanks for the explnation, sorry if my post is ambiguous. emm. in my case i need to access $value (from $output1) and $value (from $output2) independently. how to do that? thanks

Comment: What does that mean? What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: $value form $output1 and $output2 has different text. is that visible to access individually?

Comment: Why does it have different text? Both `$value`s are the same variable! Seriously, please provide an example of what you expect the result to be or do.

Comment: you can visit here : labs.herlambang.tk , type "smartfren", choose "produk..", $output1 is text under "klasifikasi positif" $output2 is text under "klasifikasi negatif"

Comment: And what does this have to do with `$value`?

Answer (score 1):

In a regular programming language like PHP, when you assign a value to a variable, the part of program which was used to built the value won't be kept by the machine. So you can't simply get back the originating values which where involved to compute a variable.

However, your example deals with strings (text). You can extract back portions of text included in such a string by using tools like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php